# Web Api call using IHTTP Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am using an HttpModule to call WebAPI. **Currently the solution is working locally in the system** but once i published the code in Server,it fails to make the API call.Here is the Sample Code:

```
   public class AppModule: IHttpModule
{
     public void Init(HttpApplication httpApp)
    {
        httpApp.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
        httpApp.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        httpApp.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnHeaderSent;
    }
      public void OnBeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpApp = (HttpApplication)sender;
                    if (httpApp.Request.Path.StartsWith("/media/")) return;
                    string a = httpApp.Request.ServerVariables["ID"];
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
                    {
                        a = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ID"];
                    }
                    var absolutepath = httpApp.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                    var values = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "ID", a },
                        { "Browser",httpApp.Request.Browser["Type"] },
                        { "Url",httpApp.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + httpApp.Request.Url.Authority + absolutepath},
                        { "OperatingSys",httpApp.Request.Headers["User-Agent"] },
                        { "IPAddss",httpApp.Request.UserHostAddress },
                        { "LDate",System.DateTime.Now.ToString() },
                    };

                        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        var appData = serializer.Deserialize<DataVO>(serializer.Serialize(values));
                        AppModuleVO objAppModuleVO = new AppModuleVO();
                        //AppModuleVo has all the properties.
                        objAppModuleVO.WebUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"] + MethodCall;
                        objAppModuleVO.objDataVo = appData;
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandlePostRequest), objAppModuleVO);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
}
```

I have registered the same in Web.Config as

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="AppModule" type="Fighter.Modules.AppModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="AppModule" type="Fighter.Modules.AppModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I am not sure whether any changes or registration needs to be made in the IIS server after publishing the code in server.**Note: I have also deployed the API in the server and provided the correct path and since other methods can call the same API that is ruled out**. Please help .The problem seems to be because of the **IIS** currently I am using IIS 7.0 in Managed Pipeline mode as **CLASSIC**.Any workarounds for this issue.

Comment: What fails? There's a catch. Is it going there?

Comment: @Asken it works perfectly when i run the solution locally the problem comes after publishing the code in the server.

Comment: Need more data... it can be anything. You'll have to look at the iis logs. Also you could try to make a dead simple module returning something like a string to see if it works. If there is a call to external sites you might have to make sure you have the right to do so. If you have control over the server you can try to set `<trust level="Full" />`.

Comment: @lincolnk  can you please help

Comment: @Asken the problem seems to be because of the IIS 7.0 in classic mode.Is there any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To long for a comment so... try this in your web.config:

```
....
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="AppModule" type="Fighter.Modules.AppModule"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Having said that you should consider using IntegratedMode.

Comment: Are you sure it will work in classic mode because can't change the server configuration to integrated because of this part of the project other dependencies might be effected.

Comment: Nothing is for sure but at least the integrated validation will be removed. The other option is to create a new application pool using integrated. If you then use that for your app it will not interfere with the other ones. They will be quite separate and can be stopped, started and recycled regardless of each other.